# Perl GET page content seems to be returning the last line of the HTML?

Tags: perl, get

I have the below code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple qw(get);

my $content = get('http://www.w3schools.com/');
print $content;
```

My problem is, the last line, which was supposed to be printing the entire page content is only displaying "". So I assume it is the last line of the file? What do you think guys? And how can I then get the entire page content then? The references that I've read that the above code is supposed to return the entire, but apparently, it did not. :-(

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: I copied your code and tried it locally. It worked fine and produced 665 lines of content.

Comment: ouch! that's my problem now. :-( when all articles in the internet is telling, and like you also mentioned, worked perfectly. very strange server i have. :-(

Comment: hi again, I think I know what's my problem now. i am actually calling the Perl script from my PHP file. And I think, the PHP is "echoing" the last line of the html file. Geesh! it's been days that I've been figuring this out! waaaah! thanks Spazm for taking time to reply. :-)

Comment: you code runs perfect!!!.. i checked my side. Might be u doing something else than this code too??

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

hi again, I think I know what's my problem now. i am actually calling the Perl script from my PHP file. And I think, the PHP is "echoing" the last line of the html file. Geesh! it's been days that I've been figuring this out! waaaah! thanks Spazm for taking time to reply. :-) –  RobEarth Softworks